# Problem intalling Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu

When I try to install I don't get the option to install alongside with windows but I only have the option of creating partition! What should I do to install alongside with windows? Please help me !

Comment: Personally, when installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, I first boot windows, defragment, back up any data, and resize the C: drive from within windows. Leave free space. Then boot Ubuntu and install into the free space. The above link has great advice on any additional issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it doesn't see Windows. Is it Windows 8? If so, try booting into Win, restart the pc and than boot into Ubuntu Live.